# changing font-weight on Roboto changes the text alignment

Tags: css, fonts

I have changed the primary font to roboto. I noticed some elements are now misaligned.

Minimal example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pzxLwd54/

Notice how "Peter" is slightly misaligned, about 1 px below "Name":

[image: 1]

It seems to be a problem with the combination of `Roboto` and the `font-weight: 500;`.
If I change the font-weight of `.value` to `600`, everything is fine again.

Is there a way to get the alignment right with a font-weight of 500?

(Tested in Chrome)

@biberman asked me to add a stack snippet which I'm happy to provide. I have reduced the original example even further. If I run this example in Chrome 90.0.4430.212 I get this result:

[image]

```css
html{
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif
}
foo-entry{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start
}

.value{
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<foo-entry>
  <div class="label">Name</div>
  <div class="value"><div>Peter</div></div>
</foo-entry>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue with your fiddle (chrome and firefox). Could you please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)